# jQuery if any item in collection has data-id equal foo

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, collections, jquery-data

Imagine I have a collection of `.item` divs. Each with it's own `data-item-id` attribute. I want to check if any of the `.data .items` has a `data-item-id` equal to `x`.

Because if *any* of the items have that id, I will not be adding that `.item` again to the `.data` listing div.

How can I do this using jQuery?

```
if ($('.data .items').data('itemId')) { ????
}
```

Comment: $("[data-item-id=foo]")

Answer (score 2):

This should return items where data-item-id is equal to x:

```
var items = $('.data .items[data-item-id="x"]');
```

or like this:

```
var items = $('.data .items').filter(function() { return $(this).data('item-id') == 'x'; });
```

And in an if:

```
if (items.length) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code.

```
 $('.data .items[data-item-id=foo]').DoSomething(function(){ 
    //Do something. 
 });  
 //This filters the elements having this attribute and value as x.
```